# Calculate percentage of value occurrence over time in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R, sorry if this is something that's been asked and solved already - have tried searching around all morning, but I'm not sure if I've been able to word it correctly.

I'd like to be able to calculate the percentage of the occurrence of a value over time. For example, I have a table with two columns, day number and input value.

Would it be possible to calculate and then mutate in the percentage of the occurrence of a specific value in relation to the day number and the previous occurrences?  i.e.

```
Day     Value     Percentage
1         1          1.00
2         1          1.00
3         2          ... 
4         1          ...
```

The ultimate goal is for this to be displayed in a curve plot showing the use of value 1 over a total period of time.

There might be a better way rather than using percentages here. It's what's coming to mind initially for me.

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: How is the `percentage` field calculated for the 4 rows shown in the example?

Comment: @user10915156 The data I'm working with is relating to if testers in an application complete a set of tasks each day. There are three values; 1 = complete, 2 = partial, 3 = no data.

I've been asked to plot a curve graph over time showing the total percentage of completions over the full range of dates, relative to the date that entry was completed against. Sorry for not being clear, will try to explain further if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using `replace`

```
dat$Percentage <- with(dat,
                       replace(cumsum(Value == 1) / seq_along(Value), Value != 1, NA))
dat
#   Day Value Percentage
#1    1     1  1.0000000
#2    2     1  1.0000000
#3    3     1  1.0000000
#4    4     2         NA
#5    5     1  0.8000000
#6    6     2         NA
#7    7     2         NA
#8    8     1  0.6250000
#9    9     1  0.6666667
#10  10     1  0.7000000
```

---

In case you want this calculation for all distinct values in the `Value` column you can do

```
dat$Percentage2 <- with(dat,
                        ave(Value, Value, FUN = seq_along) / seq_len(dim(dat)[1]))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Day = 1:10,
                  Value = sample(1:2, 10, TRUE, prob = c(.7, .3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the data provided by @markus, one `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(temp = seq_along(Day) - cumsum(Value != 1),
        Percentage = ifelse(Value != 1, NA, temp * 100/seq_along(Day))) %>%
 select(-temp)

   Day Value Percentage
1    1     1  100.00000
2    2     1  100.00000
3    3     1  100.00000
4    4     2         NA
5    5     1   80.00000
6    6     2         NA
7    7     2         NA
8    8     1   62.50000
9    9     1   66.66667
10  10     1   70.00000
```

Comment: That's great, thank you! I've ticked @markus' reply as I ran with that before seeing this, but this also does the trick.

Once I get enough rep, I'll come back and upvote!